# Time out issue when posting json data to node api

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postman

I'm having timeout issues when posting json data over 100kb to a nodejs api with postman.  I've tested my api function on the client side and had zero issues.  When i moved it to a node server and feed it json input via postman, it only works on smaller datasets such as 20kb.  On the client side, it was tested with data up to 20mb.  I've checked postman settings and the request timeout is set to infinity.  I don't think I should be running into node's json size limit, but i can't figure out where to begin looking...

Comment: Are you saying that the same API endpoint handles the data up to 20 mb from client app and Postman times out for that same endpoint for the same data?

Comment: No, i'm saying I can run the js function entirely in the browser and it works fine.  When i move the function to a node server and post to it with postman it behaves as I described.

Comment: I think it should do something with Node server. When you make a request, can you check the logs? Maybe you are setting off some infinite loop in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says that for NodeJS server with ExpressJS(I am assuming that you are using that) has the default request json size of 100kb. Its [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#limit-3).

You can easily set the limit higher like this:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb'}));
```

Comment: Thanks, that sent me on the right direction.  I actually had to set the limit for json: app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));